# Return integer using TclTK from C library

Tags: r, c, tcl

I have C code that uses Tcl/Tk library. I then create a library using this C code which is then linked to R language package. I have a function in the C code:

```
int doSomething(){
   if(TRUE){
      return TCL_OK;
   else{
      TCL_RESULT3("Error")
      return TCL_OK;
}
```

Currently, I use `TCL_RESULT3("Error")` in the C code, and then in R check if `result <- tclvalue(tcl(...)) #calls doSomething()` returns a string with `Error`:

```
if (startsWith(result, "Error"))
        {
            return(FALSE)
        }
        return(TRUE)
```

and base further actions in R on the returned value.

However, even though there is an error, I still call `TCL_OK` because `TCL_ERROR` produces something that R cannot seem to handle (at least it is not straightforward). My question is if it is possible to restructure my function as:

```
int doSomething(){
   if(TRUE){
      return TCL_OK;
   else{
      return TCL_ERROR;
}
```

and have R understand what is being returned. Currently, if `TCL_OK` is returned, then `result` will be an empty string `""`. If `TCL_ERROR` is returned, then result will yield: `Error in structure(.External(.C_dotTclObjv, objv), class = "tclObj") : [tcl] .` which R does not know how to handle.

Is it possible to have R handle such an error (i.e. return a value of FALSE if this error pops up) or is checking for an error message using `TCL_RESULT3()` in conjunction with `TCL_OK` the best method for such a process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your C code returns `TCL_ERROR` (instead of `TCL_OK`) that's an error condition, which is logically like an exception in other languages. Can R handle those? [Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r) (apparently; I know very little R). Here's one way (there are others, of course; the right choice depends on what you're doing and the likely cause of the exception).

```
result <- tryCatch(
    {
        # This is where you put in the code to call into Tcl
        tclvalue(tcl(...)) # calls doSomething()
    },
    error = function(err) {
        message(paste("error occurred in Tcl code:", err))
        return(NaN)   # Need an alternative result value here
    }
)
```

Note that if you're calling an arbitrary Tcl command, you pretty much have to handle exceptions. Failures are a fact of life, and you need to allow for them in robust code.

Comment: Some types of error might be better handled on the Tcl side of course. There there's a fairly sophisticated `try` command to help out. It's logically similar to `tryCatch()` in R, but more adapted to the way a different language works. There's also an older `catch` command, but that really does expose some peculiarities.